# 'str' object has no attribute 'visited'

Tags: python, class

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes={}
        self.visited = False
        self.discovered = False


    def vertices(self):
        return self.nodes.keys()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.nodes)

    def adj(self,u):
        if u in self.nodes:
            return self.nodes[u]

    def insertNode(self,u):
        if u not in self.nodes:
            self.nodes[u]={}


    def insertEdge(self,u,v,w):
        self.insertNode(u)
        self.insertNode(v)
        self.nodes[u][v]=w


def bfs(g,radix):

    queue=[radix]

    while queue:
        u=queue.pop(0)
        u.visited=True
        for v in G.adj(u):
            if not v.visited:
                queue.append(v)
    return queue


if __name__=='__main__':

    g = Graph()
    for u, v, w in [('a', 'b', 3), ('a', 'd', 2), ('b', 'c', 5), ('c', 'd', 9), ('c', 'e', 1), ('d', 'e', 4)]:
       g.insertEdge(u, v, w)

bfs(g,'a')
```

My problem is that when I call:

```
bfs(g,'a')
```

PyCharm returns:

```
u.visited=True
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'visited'
```

Comment: Well, `u` is a string, `'a'`. Because that's what you pass as second argument to `bfs`. You probably expect it to be something else.

Comment: I think you meant it to be `g.visited` but that doesn't help you much either.

Comment: You're not allowed to add custom attributes to built-in string objects.

Comment: It seems like you need a `Node` class to go along with the `Graph` class. A graph should be a collection of connected nodes. And the nodes should have the `visited` attribute.

Comment: Oh ok Barmar, i'm new in Python i didn't thought about that at all. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The method `pop()` removes the element from list and returns it.
So `u=queue.pop(0)` is removing `'a'` and it is also returning it.
And the error is genereted here:

```
u.visited=True
```

Because string `'a'` doesn't have an attribute called `visited`.

Answer (score 0):

You passed the string value to the `radix` variable. After that you set the queue to be equal to the array that has `radix` in it, so in the while loop `u` becomes `'a'` and then you try to call `.visited` attribute on it which is not possible because string doesn't have a visited attribute.

Comment: Ok it is clear, i wanted to pass in bfs the radix of my graph, how could i pass the radix in bfs without using 'a' ?